# IdentityServer3: Deny access to given scope based on user claims

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver3, oauth-2.0

I have a WebAPI with 2 areas - user and admin. 2 sites, user and admin, use it, they have their own client ids.

```
    public static readonly Scope AdminScope = new Scope
    {
        Name = "adm_api",
        Type = ScopeType.Resource,
        Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
        {
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role),
            new ScopeClaim(VitClaimTypes.IsAdmin)
        },
    };

    public static readonly Scope UserScope = new Scope
    {
        Name = "user_api",
        Type = ScopeType.Resource,
        Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
        {
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role),
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Name),
        }
    };
```

Clients:

```
        new Client
        {
            ClientName = "User area client",
            ClientId = "user_client",
            Enabled = true,

            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
            {
                "user_api", "offline_access"
            }
        },

        new Client
        {
            ClientName = "Admin area client",
            ClientId = "adm_client",
            Enabled = true,

            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
            {
                "user_api", "adm_api"
            }
        },
```

Now I want to deny login for users who request 'adm_api' scope but do not have IsAdmin claim. How do I do that? I know that I can add a custom Authorize attribute to the API, and I will do that. But it would be more user-friendly to deny access right away on login than to wait for the first API access.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would rather be your admin applications responsibility to check for the issued claims and inform the user of insufficient access before requesting api resources. It wouldn't be correct for identity service to deny login, after all, there is nothing wrong with authentication. This sounds more like authorization.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted your intention originally. I've now edited the answer. Hope that helps

Comment: I agree that it sounds more like authorization. But on the other hand, on login the user asks for access to scopes, like "read" or "write", or "admin_scope". What should the server do if the user does not have permission to a requested scope? If you say that it is wrong to deny login, then the server should exclude from the token scopes that the user is not allowed to, right? How can I do that?

Comment: No, the user doesn't ask for scopes, the application does. Your admin app will - as it should - ask for admin scope, and identity service will - as it should - authenticate the user. But if your user doesn't have the required claim, than that is authorization and should be up to your admin app to inform the user about.

Comment: Do you mean that it is wrong to deny access to a certain scope based on the user's claims?

Comment: No, I mean you're mixing up two concepts. The scope access is given to your applications Oauth client, not the user. Clearly, your admin app needs the admin scope access, otherwise it won't be able to do what it should. On the other hand, authenticated user might not have the claims your application requires from him and it would be the applications responsibility to show "Access denied" page if that's the case, before making API requests.

Comment: You are talking about role-based authorization, but what if I want to make it scope-based? I want to mark some parts of my API with a custom [Authorize] attribute, something like [AdminScope]. In that attribute I will check if the access token's 'scope' claim has 'admin_scope' in it. If it doesn't, I will reject the request. Admin scope can be issued only by the Admin client. Now, a user that is allowed to use user_api but not admin_api, may try to login in the Admin page. In this case I should either reject authorization request OR not include the "admin_scope" in the result token. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134171/discussion-between-dmitry-and-danijels).